# Trying to deploy multiple functions following deploy instruction result in ERROR, too many arg

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have an index.js with some exports in it that each includes only one function. I try to deploy a few of them at once and CLI gives me the error below;

```
Error: Too many arguments. Run firebase help deploy for usage instructions
```

What am I doing wrong? based on the --help I can use something like this:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:func1,functions:func2
```

**Additional Info:** I'm using firebase CLI v3.9.2. Following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys) I have restructured my functions to be in format of

```
exports.groupA = {

func1: functions.https.onRequest(...),

func2: functions.database.ref('\path').onWrite(...),

}
```

and still doesn't work! not sure why.I run something like

```
firebase deploy --only functions:groupA.func1,func2
```

or

```
firebase deploy --only functions:groupA.func1,functions:groupA.func2
```

and many more variations .. with no luck.

Comment: It should work when supplying the right functions names I suppose.

Comment: Are you running a recent version of the CLI tools?  The current version is 3.9.2.  Use `firebase -V` to see the version.  If not recent, [get the latest version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#getting_the_latest_version) with `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version. My only guess is that it might be because I have all the functions in one file?! I don't know, can't think of anything else!

Answer (score 0):

```
exports const func1 = functions.https.onRequest(...),

exports const func2 = functions.database.ref('\path').onWrite(...),
```

then deploy by

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```